# What's the purpose of php encoders if the end-user can't view the php source anyway?

Tags: php

I have a bluehost account and I have the option of using ioncube, source guardian, or neither.  What is the benefit of encoding the php if the end-user can't see the source anyway?  Are there other benefits other then encoding?

Is ioncube preferred to source guardian?

thanks,
me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP code obfuscation is generally used when you need to license a PHP application to someone else.  You don't want the person getting the code to install on their server to be able to easily copy the code.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this actually makes sense.  So can you answer my other two questions?  Like are there benefits to encoding anyways?  I read it makes your code get processed more quickly.

Comment: IonCube compiles your code, making it faster.  If you have your choice, that'd generally be the way to go.

Comment: Great, ty.  So you recommend ioncube over no php encoding for an application that I won't license to anybody, provided ioncube is free?

Comment: My philosophy is always to "use what you need".  If you need it, sure.  If not, don't bother.  You should also do your own benchmarking.